# Passing data to custom UITableViewCell class

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am trying to pass an Integer variable from cellForRowAtIndexpath to Custom UITableViewcell. i tried with below code but the integer variable is always nil in custom cell.

```
// TableView intialisation

            tableView = UITableView() // delcared in class level
            tableView.frame = self.view.bounds
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.separatorColor = .clear
            self.view.addSubview(tableView)
            tableView.register(TodoListTVCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(tableView)
    
    
 //  Cell for row at indexpath 

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TodoListTVCell
    
            cell.picsTag = objectsArray[indexpath.row].picsTag   
            
            return cell
    
    }
    
    
// custom tableview cell
    class TodoListTVCell : UITableViewCell{
        
        var picsTag : Int!
        
        override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
            super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
            self.selectionStyle = .none
            
            print("index tag \(picsTag)")
    
        }
        
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    
    }
```

PS : I don't want use global variables, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `init` the place where you are seeing `nil`?  If so, that is to be expected since the initialiser will complete before you assign anything to the property.

Comment: Yes , that is the problem @paulw11

Comment: init function is being called before you set the picsTag.

Comment: There is no way `picsTag` can be non-nil in `init`, but that really shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yes , but what is the solution?

Comment: Your code is absolutely fine but isn't really clear what you are trying to achieve. You are setting the value in the right way but accessing it at wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom function and call this function after set all cell properties.

```
//  Cell for row at indexpath 

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TodoListTVCell
    
        cell.picsTag = objectsArray[indexpath.row].picsTag   
        cell.printPicsTag()
            
        return cell
    
    }


// custom tableview cell
   class TodoListTVCell : UITableViewCell{
    
    var picsTag : Int!
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.selectionStyle = .none
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func printPicsTag() {
        print("index tag \(picsTag)")
    }
 
 }
```